# Can't update table that trigger is executed on in AFTER INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers

I'm running MySQL 5.5.9 and InnoDB.

I try to create a versioned table, where the `current` field indicates whether a record is the most recent version. Something like:

```
| autonumber | id | name | current
| 1          | 1  | Yes  | 0
| 2          | 1  | No   | 1
```

Anyhow, I did this in the past in MSSQL quite often via an `AFTER INSERT` trigger that updates all records with the same id to `current = 0`. So here we go in MySQL:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_Products_UpdateEarlierVersions AFTER INSERT ON Products
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE Products
    SET current = 0
    WHERE   id = new.id
        AND current = 1
        AND autonumber <> new.autonumber;
END;
|
```

This runs fine, but when inserting a record:

```
insert into Products (id, name)
values (1, "Hello SO!");
```

I get the following error:

> Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'Products' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Is there a way around this to achieve a similar thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taken from here http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,122505#msg-122505

> when you insert a record mysql is doing some lock stuff. you can't
>   insert/update/delete rows of the same table where you insert.. because
>   then the trigger would called again and again.. ending up in a
>   recursion

Comment: you are locking it :))) it's the way it works if you update something it gets locked. either row,page,table and so on. as i wrote try and use BEFORE trigger.

Answer (score 1):

when you insert a record mysql is doing some lock stuff. you can't insert/update/delete rows of the same table where you insert.. because then the trigger would called again and again.. ending up in a recursion

I used to have this problem. I removed the update command. So, try this one:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_Products_UpdateEarlierVersions AFTER INSERT ON Products
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    SET current = 0
    WHERE   id = new.id
        AND current = 1
        AND autonumber <> new.autonumber;
END;
|
```

I think this is gonna work

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, it is not possible to update a table ('Products') for which the trigger is created in the trigger.

According to MySQL documentation, this error is generated to prevent infinite recursion: when an UPDATE occurs, the trigger is run and updates the table, this trigger UPDATE causes the trigger to run again, and again, and again which ends up in an infinite loop.

Comment: That's what the error says but I'm looking for a way around it.

Comment: eventually try to use BEFORE trigger

Comment: BEFORE trigger yields the same, but it wasn't an option because a failing INSERT statement will screw your database in that case.

Comment: how can a failing insert screw a db if you put it in a transaction?

Answer (score 0):

This is 5 years old, but I was hitting the same problem as the OP's, ended up here, followed @Sergey Benner's link to forum.mysql.com and found the following at [Re: Can't update table 'tbl' in stored function/trigger...](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?99,122354,201300#msg-201300):

> I know this is an old post but I stumbled on the answer and thought I would share. During the insert/update you have access to the NEW object which contains all of the fields in the table involved. If you do a before insert/update and edit the field(s) that you want to change in the new object it will become a part of the calling statement and not be executed as a separately (eliminating the recursion)
>   ex.
>
> create trigger test before update on test
>
> for each row
>
> set NEW.updateTime = NOW();

What's sad for the OP is that this post is from March 18, 2008, many years before the post here. I guess the other members who replied just did not dive deep enough into the forum.mysql thread to discover this. That forum has a very unfriendly presentation - StackOverflow definitely rules.

I have tested this in my context and it works beautifully. I hate to be called "trigger -happy", but if the hat fits...