# mySQL trigger cannot update table : already in use by the statement that invoked the trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

so i've edited my code 
i had this problem in another trigger but this time even changing WHERE clause doesn't help

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER pic_album_change  AFTER UPDATE  ON pictures
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    UPDATE albums SET counter = counter + 1 WHERE albums.id = NEW.album_id;
    UPDATE albums SET counter = counter - 1 WHERE albums.id = OLD.album_id;


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

error :

```
    <p>Error Number: 1442</p><p>Can't update table 'pictures' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

i dont see any changes  on the  pictures table in this trigger

i have another trigger that involves these two tables

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER  album_change
  AFTER UPDATE
  ON albums
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE pictures
     SET

      level = NEW.level


    WHERE
   pictures.album_id =  NEW.id   ;


END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227382/cant-update-table-that-trigger-is-executed-on-in-after-insert

Comment: I *think* your `WHERE` clause is the wrong way round. `WHERE albums.id = NEW.album.id` would cause `albums.counter` to be incremented (presumably that's the number of pictures in each album).

Comment: @radashk thanks for the link but as i said my trigger is not attached on the same table

Comment: @Andrew Leach thank you this is it  . weird though , why would this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is the wrong way round.

```
WHERE albums.id = NEW.album_id
```

would cause `albums.counter` to be incremented (presumably that's the number of pictures in each album).

It matters because joins on tables are not commutative — the direction of the join is important. Here you need to find the record in `albums` to update based on the value of the row in `pictures`.

While *in this case* there isn't really any ambiguity, SQL needs to follow rules about joins.

---

The issue with your second trigger is that MySQL is preventing a continuous cycle of updates. You have a trigger `pic_album_change` which updates `albums` when `pictures` is updated. And you have a trigger `album_change` which updates `pictures` when `albums` is updated. Those triggers will trigger each other.

It seems to me that the database design may need to be changed. Do you really need `albums.counter` when that data can be found with `SELECT count(*) FROM pictures WHERE album_id=...`? It should be possible to normalise data so that there no circular references in triggers. In fact triggers may not be necessary at all.

Comment: thanx andrew sorry to bother you but i have he same problem in another trigger . i have no idea what could be the problem . i did edit my code

Comment: @max I don't think it's on to edit the old question out in its entirety because that invalidates the answer. And in fact other triggers might have a bearing on how this one behaves. What other triggers on `pictures` do you have?

Comment: i'm sorry you right i shouldn't edit the question . however i found another trigger that involves these two table i think i have to somehow merge or rewrite them so they wouldn't conflict with each other

Comment: well it's kinda like a picture management system with different album and pictures for each user . so tables are going to be very big and heavy . i think it's going to be much faster to use trigger . anyway i've removed the second trigger . i wish phpmyadmin  had some kind of trigger management tools