# MySQL field set to 0 on update

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to set a field to 0 whenever that row gets updated without using PHP or explicitly including that in my queries?

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default value `= 0` when defining the table.

From [CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html):

```
CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
   .../...
column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
```

Let's say

```
CREATE TABLE test (
a INT,
b INT DEFAULT 0);
```

If we do

```
INSERT INTO test (a) values (1),(2),(3);
```

Then when we

```
SELECT * FROM test
```

we will get

```
a  |  b
1     0
2     0
3     0
```

See it working on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05e83/1)

Comment: The field already has a default value set. What I need is the value of that field to get changed back to 0 (if it was updated to something else before) if there is an update done to that row.

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, it is a matter of creating a trigger, like @Sebastian is suggesting. Hope a mixure of answers help you.

Answer (score 1):

Use a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_zero AFTER UPDATE ON table_name
   FOR EACH ROW
      UPDATE table_name SET col_name=0 WHERE xyz=cond_xyz;
;
```

Didn't test it.

Comment: Yes. This looks like something that might work. I'll have to do more research into how to apply this to my actual use case. Thanks.

Comment: How would I go about just updating that one row? This seems like it would update all rows. I see the WHERE clause, but how would I put in `WHERE id="ID of only the row that was updated"`

Comment: I don't know! But I found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334478/mysql-triggers-cannot-update-rows-in-same-table-the-trigger-is-assigned-to-sugg which says that my code above will cause infinite recursion which is true. It also has a solution. ANother thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227382/cant-update-table-that-trigger-is-executed-on-in-after-insert says that using `BEFORE` will do the trick.

Comment: MySQL uses row level triggers, you don't `update` the table, you just assign values to the `new` record that is being passed into the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed like a bizarre request to me at first, but it actually is possible in MySQL.  If you specify `0` as the default for that field, you can take advantage of the fact that `REPLACE INTO` uses defaults for unspecified but existing columns.

```
INSERT INTO t1 (id, numToZero, value) VALUES (1, 1345, 'value');
```

Later, when you want to update:

```
REPLACE INTO t1 (id, value) VALUES (1, 'new value');
```

This will yield `(1, 0, 'new value')` without creating a new row.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger is the right way to go, but Sebastian got it all wrong.

You don't run `UPDATE` inside a trigger you just assign the value to the `new` record that is being passed to the trigger. Additionally it *has* to be a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger (because a change to the `new` record in an **AFTER** trigger won't be persisted).

```
CREATE TRIGGER set_zero 
  BEFORE UPDATE ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET new.col_name = 0; 
END;
```

Note that you can still supply a non-zero value during *insert* even if a default value is defined. If you don't want that either, you also need an insert trigger

Here is an SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cebe82/1